# How do l find IDs that have been together throughout the timing using SQL query

Tags: sql

How do l find IDs that have been together throughout the timing using SQL query, using the sample data below:

[image]

Expected outcome: 825652, 179386 & 531348.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM mytable)
```

Comment: Thanks Adish, that's fast! :)

Comment: I tried to do a count, but why izzit showing 5 instead of 3? SELECT id, count(*) size 
FROM test 
GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Timestamp) FROM test)

Comment: 5 is the count of distinct dates. It is showing all ids which have 5 entries, 1 for each date.

Comment: Oic.. How to get the 3 then pls, which shows there're 3 IDs?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (put in your query here) myalias